# "origin_Mismatch" while using checkSession() in auth0-js

Tags: javascript, token, auth0

I am using auth0-js npm package js in my react application , on using the checkSession() i am getting an error states The redirectUri's origin (https://localhost) should match the window's origin (https://localhost:44372).

i have intialized auth0 variable:

below is my js code:

```
const auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
domain: "mydomain",
clientID: "myclientID",
redirectUri: 'https://localhost://44372',
responseType: 'code'
});
```

and this is the checkSession method I'm calling

```
auth.checkSession({
     responseType: 'token',
     redirectUri: 'https://localhost://44372',
     scope: 'openid profile email offline_access read:contacts 
     read:calendar update:current_user_identities',
     usePostMessage: true
     }, function (err, result) {

        if (err) 
        {
             console.log(err)    
        }
        else 
        {
             alert(result.idToken)
        }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Often times with issues like these it's found they are indeed not a one for one match. I would recommend taking another look at your RedirectURI and what is actually in your Auth0 Dashboard. I have linked a commonly referenced doc on this front. I hope this helps you in your quest!

- https://auth0.com/docs/users/guides/redirect-users-after-login